# Android Jelly bean 4.2.2 - webview XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: android, webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

In my app I'm using  `WebView`. I'm trying to call POST method that cannot proceed my request.I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://*****/support/create_ticket.
>   Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers. at null:1

**It's happening only in device with Jelley bean 4.2.2 in all the other OS it's work fine**.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to request headers:

```
Map<String, String> extraHeaders=new HashMap<>();
extraHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
extraHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

You might need to add this too:

```
extraHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST");//you add more:"GET, POST, PUT"
```

--- Updated based on your code, here is the adjustment:

```
RestAPI.Groups = $resource('groups/:id', {
    id: '@id'
}, {
    get: {
        method: "GET",
        KalseferPrivateAPI: true,
        interceptor: Interceptors.get
    },
    join: method: "POST",
    KalseferPrivateAPI: true,
    interceptor: Interceptors.post,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST'
    },
    url: 'groups/join'
}, addMember: {
    method: "POST",
    KalseferPrivateAPI: true,
    interceptor: Interceptors.post,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST'
    },
    url: 'groups/:id/users/:users',
    params: {
        id: '@id',
        users: '@users'
    }
}
});
```

I hope that may help,'.

Comment: I want to refine the question, i load url to the webview and in this page i have a button that after we clicked it we call to java script function that throw the error :  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://*****/support/create_ticket. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. at null:1.   I'm not sure that the fix need to be in the android native code.

Comment: Please to provide the code how your javascript request looks like.. you need to add above map to your request header.

Comment: Each request holds header map.a set of key-value pair. In wont be different in your case. If you could provide me how your request via Javascript .. I can show you how to set headers. because I have no idea if its ajax call or XMLHttpRequest call.  Thats the reason why I have asked for code or more info

Comment: This is the function in the server that throw the error, i hope it will help:<br/>RestAPI.Groups = $resource( 'groups/:id',{id: '@id'}, {get: {method: "GET",KalseferPrivateAPI: true, interceptor: Interceptors.get},join: method: "POST", KalseferPrivateAPI: true,interceptor: Interceptors.post,url: 'groups/join'},addMember: {
                method: "POST",
                KalseferPrivateAPI: true,
                interceptor: Interceptors.post,
                url: 'groups/:id/users/:users',
                params: {id: '@id', users: '@users'} }});